# What does the 'S' linux file permission mean

Tags: linux, permissions

I've seen various Linux file permissions such as `rwx` and `rws`, but I have never seen the permission set `rwS`. Can someone please explain to me what the capitol 'S' stands for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The capital S indicates the file has a setuid bit set but is not executable.

```
[root@host:/]$ touch file
[root@host:/]$ chmod 4755 file
[root@host:/]$ ls -l file
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 25 15:05 file
[root@host:/]$ chmod -x file
[root@host:/]$ ls -l file
-rwSr--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 25 15:05 file
```

Answer (score 7):

From `info ls "What information is listed"`:

```
    `S'
          If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit is set but the
          corresponding executable bit is not set.
```